# jQuery selector for HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have this button with multiple data attributes, and i want to hide it by selecting it based on class and two data attributes.

```
<a href='#' class='wishlist-icon' data-wish-name='product' data-wish-url='/product'>Button</a>

$(".wishlist-icon [data-wish-name='product'] [data-wish-url='/product']").hide();
```

I don't know why this selector doesn't work.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m9BxD/)

Comment: The space is the *descendant selector*. You are looking for an element `[data-wish-url='/product']` *inside* an element `[data-wish-name='product']` *inside* an element `.wishlist-icon`. If you want to select an element based on multiple selectors, you have to write them together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the space between the selector.

```
$(".wishlist-icon[data-wish-name='product'][data-wish-url='/product']").hide();
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m9BxD/1/)

Comment: I know, i just had to wait for certain period :)